# how can implementing a heap that each node is a class?

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

I want to crate a Heap structure that each node have 2 data , 1) string 2) int
so i think that each node must be a Class that's name is "heapNode" , but i have a trouble in swap method ,
please help me

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainHeap {
    ArrayList<heapNode> heap;

    MainHeap (){
         new ArrayList<heapNode>();
    }

    public int getMin(){
        return heap.get(0).data ;
    }

     private int parent(int pos) {
            return  pos / 2;
    }

     private void swap(int pos1, int pos2) {
            heapNode temp =new heapNode();

            temp = heap.get(pos1);
            heap.get(pos1) = heap.get(pos2);
            heap.get(pos2) = temp;
            }
     public void insert(int elem) {

            int max = heap.size();
            heap.get(max).data = elem ;
            int current = heap.size() ;
            while (heap.get(current).data < heap.get(parent(current)).data){
                swap ( current , parent(current));
            }

        }

}
```

and this is my heapNode class

```
public class heapNode {
    int data;
    String fileName;
}
```

the swap method has error but i cant solve errors

Answer (score 2):

Your swap code actually makes the objects point to different objects. It does not modify the positions in the arraylist itself. If using arraylist, you will have to remove an object from an index and set that object at a new index to swap or else you can use other data structure.

Comment: thanks a lot can you see my following code I wander if it is true or not       private void swap(int pos1, int pos2) {
   heapNode temp =new heapNode();

   temp = heap.get(pos1);
   heap.remove(pos1);
   heap.add(pos1, heap.get(pos2));
   heap.remove(pos2);
   heap.add(pos2, temp);
      }

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.PriorityQueue<YourClass>`